# FileSystem Detection and Data Extractionave

Tags: filesystems, data-recovery

I had an old DVR system which I was recording my CCTV cameras

with it. Product is:
http://www.adk-security.com/lx-zeus-8-h264-channel-lite-silent-

with-mobile-login--usb-1240-p.asp

or in fact
http://www.qvissecurity.com/Catalogue/CEARANCE-BARGAINS/Analog-

Dvr/PROFESSIONAL-DVRs/APOLLO-PROLITE-LX/8-CHANNEL/LX-PRO-LITE-8-

Chn-1TB-LXAPOPROLITE-8-1TB

Now I found my CCTV disk, it's normal 1TB HDD. I want to see RAW

videos recorded from CCTVs in this HDD. File system is not

detected by FindAndMount, Partition Magic, Recover My Files, etc.

Windows says it's RAW disk.

I can't access videos, but when I open disk image and read sector

by sector I see data there. How can I properly read and extract

data from this disk?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

These are stored in xfs or a linux file system on this unit,

go to pendrivelinux.com and get a windows installer to make a bootable pendrive.

I prefer ubuntu or debian, choose one of the two and make a thumb drive on a fresh thumb drive.

boot that up on a computer, plug in the dvr drive via USB-ide/SATA converter (About $14) most places.

you should see the disk mount and the files will be viewable.

you can then plugin a NTFS formatted hard disk and copy those off to the external drive and view them in VLC player for windows videolan.org